# ROS and Research Robotics Career Finder

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if there were any plans on doing a "career board" for people involved in the ROS Community.

More specifically, a place where people can find jobs with companies that do research robotics and personal robotics.  Also, a place where companies can post internship, co-op, and full time job postings for members of the ROS community to see.

I'm reaching the end of my academic career, and it's never too early to start looking.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9903/ros-and-research-robotics-career-finder/) by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6414 on 2011-05-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While not ROS specific, the [robotics-worldwide](http://duerer.usc.edu/mailman/listinfo/robotics-worldwide) mailing list is a good place to find numerous postings of jobs, internships, postdoc/phd positions, and conference/journal/workshop announcements.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-05-05**:
Excellent resource, I did not know about this.  Thanks!